# Getting distinct values from multiple instances of the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to extract distinct values from a table using multiple instances of that table so, that I am only returning the distinct values.

I am trying to extract a distinct contract_id for each of the entries in the table. There are multiple entries with the same `contract_id`. Once I have that I am then trying to put all of the entries with like `contract_id's` in the same line.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (a.inspection_id) AS inspection_id,
  (a.contract_id, b.contract_id, c.contract_id) AS Contract_id,
  b.linking_id AS inspector_id,
  c.string_value AS phone
FROM inspection a, inspection b, inspection c
WHERE a.contract_id = b.contract_id
  and a.contract_id = b.contract_id
  and a.contract_id = c.contract_id
  and a.position = 0
  and b.position = 1
  and c.position = 2;
```

All I am returning is an empty output, but I know, there are values in the table.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by describing what you are really trying to do by editing the question.  Then, provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: (i) You specified `a.contract_id = b.contract_id` Is this redundant (and an error), or should it actually be two different conditions? (ii) `(a.contract_id, b.contract_id, c.contract_id) AS Contract_id` is probably counter to your intention. (iii) Please provide the table structure, and explain the purpose of the `position` column. (iv) Echoing Gordon: Please provide sample data, and expected result. -- In general, the query *could* return data: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7e562/1) - Feel free to adjust the Fiddle - with appropriate detail provided, we might be able to help.

Comment: The source of your query has a link to http://i.stack.imgur.com/KCH2c.jpg - how exactly does that relate to your problem?

Comment: Unrelated but: you should stop using the outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause and start using the modern explicit `JOIN` operators.